# Syntax error: insert } to complete ClassBody - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I don't understand why the compiler gives me the following error:

```
Syntax error: insert } to complete ClassBody
```

Here is my code:

```
package sau.se.extractor.excel;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ExcelHandler {

    public ExcelHandler() {
    };
    public void printExcelContent() {
        Workbook wrk1 = null;
        try {
            wrk1 = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(
                    "C:/Users/Houssem/Downloads/st.xls"));
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Sheet sheet1 = wrk1.getSheet(0);
        Cell colArow1 = sheet1.getCell(0, 0);
        Cell colBrow1 = sheet1.getCell(1, 0);
        Cell colArow2 = sheet1.getCell(0, 1);
        String str_colArow1 = colArow1.getContents();
        String str_colBrow1 = colBrow1.getContents();
        String str_colArow2 = colArow2.getContents();
        System.out.println("Contents of cell Col A Row 1: \"" + str_colArow1
                + "\"");
        System.out.println("Contents of cell Col B Row 1: \"" + str_colBrow1
                + "\"");
        System.out.println("Contents of cell Col A Row 2: \"" + str_colArow2
                + "\"");
    };
}
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Btw, many IDEs have an option to match the braces, so go to the braces one by one, press a certain key combination, and it shows you the matching brace.
Using Eclipse, try Ctrl+Shift+F to format the code. Or
Just Clean your Project from Project->Clean

Comment: In your code you have added semicolons(;) at the end of method. This is unnessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes, Eclipse doesn't properly clean up errors. You can try to *clean/rebuild* your project (menu: Project > Clean..), that usually does the trick.

If the error is still there, **just delete it** (no kidding): 
Select the error in the '*Problems*' view and delete it (DEL key or using the context menu). Refresh or clean your project afterwards to see if the error reappears.

Comment: I agree. The OP's post is syntactically correct.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the semicolons from after your constructor and method declarations.

Comment: I tried but in vain : (

Comment: Semicolons are just fine. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I tried to reformat it with eclipse editor, remove all spaces and tabs